# How do I rotate an object while the key is pressed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here's my code:

```
public Transform Dummy;
public Transform Sphere;


void Start () {
    Sphere.SetParent(Dummy);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        Dummy.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, new Quaternion(1, 1, 1, 0), (float)20 * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

The problem is that it rotates only once when the Space key is pressed, so I need to press it many times, which is bad. 
I need to rotate the Dummy while the space key is pressed.

Comment: Make sure to check out the [unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/index.html). It's got lots of great information for beginners and experts alike!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [GetKey](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html), and not [GetKeyDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html), if you want a continuous rotation.